# php - Can i compare string with array?

Tags: php, arrays

i am getting category name using `$_GET['category']`

and assigning it to `$category` like this.

// if  $_GET['category'] contains space then create array of categories

```
if(strpos($_GET['category'],' ') !== false) {

$category = explode (' ',$_GET['category']);

}else{

$category = $_GET['category'];

}
```

so `$category` can either be an **array** or **string**

and i have dropdown select box on website and would like to show the user searched category by setting **selected="selected"** to the specific option in dropdown select.

so my question is **can i compare string with an array ?**, without checking if its an array , like this.

```
<option value="option1"<?= (isset($category) && ($category == 'option1')) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?>>option1</option>
<option value="option2"<?= (isset($category) && ($category == 'option2')) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?>>option2</option>
<option value="option3"<?= (isset($category) && ($category == 'option3')) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?>>option3</option>
<option value="option4"<?= (isset($category) && ($category == 'option4')) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?>>option4</option>
```

or i have to check whether the `$category` is not an array like this.

```
<option value="option1"<?= (isset($category) && (!is_array($category)) && ($category == 'option1')) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?>>option1</option>
<option value="option2"<?= (isset($category) && (!is_array($category)) && ($category == 'option2')) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?>>option2</option>
<option value="option3"<?= (isset($category) && (!is_array($category)) && ($category == 'option3')) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?>>option3</option>
<option value="option4"<?= (isset($category) && (!is_array($category)) && ($category == 'option4')) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?>>option4</option>
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: instead of string, if you can make `$category` as an array, it would be easier for you. In `else block`, if you will write `$category = array($_GET['category']);`, then in your HTML code, you can check with only array not with string.

Answer (score 2):

you need not to set category value as a string.
just use as following.

```
if(isset($_GET['category'])) { 
$category = explode (' ',$_GET['category']);
}

<option value="option1"<?= (isset($category) && in_array('option1', $category)) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?>>option1</option>
<option value="option2"<?= (isset($category) && in_array('option2', $category)) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?>>option2</option>
```

Comment: thatys not the issue here , the issue is do  have to check whether given data is array or not before comparing it to the string.

Comment: @amb You code wrongly. You get a good advice. You should not say ' This is not the issue here. '

Comment: @AMB if you compare a string with an array you'll always get `false`. You could have tested that yourself in a couple of minutes. This answer is a good method for doing what you want.

Comment: @MikeW i tried with both cases and its working fine but wanted to make sure it wont cause any issue after .

Comment: sorry for the downvote , i didnt read the whole answer, just made my descision after i saw isset, please edit the answer so i can remove downvote.

Answer (score 1):

You should always use explode. Like this you get always an array.

```
$category = explode (' ',$_GET['category']);
```

After, you can test if the value is in the array with

```
if(in_array($option, $category)) echo 'selected="selected";
```

Answer (score 0):

of course you can test an array with a string witout testing if it is array or it is string .. but you should test if the variable `isset` because empty string is equal to null value if you're using the operator `==`like you did on your code , otherwise you can use the `===` instead